# iPhone SDK: SearchDisplayController with Core Data Table Sample Code?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Are there any good samples of using a SearchDisplayController with a Core Data backed tableview? None of the Apple samples I see use Core Data, NSFetchedResultController or NSPredicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/coredatatutorial/index.html

checkout the 6th link "Adding the Search Field"